# Vertically aligning <div> with one <form type="text"> and 2 <span>s

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

I'm looking to align one of my `<div>` containers which has a nested `<form ype="text">` and 2 `<span>` tags but I can't seem to apply a `margin-top: 6px;` to the container `<div>`.

Would `padding-top: 6px;` be the answer?

Comment: Not 100% sure on what you mean. You want to have a `<div>` that has a textbox in it align (vertically?) to two `<span>` tags?

Comment: Well, I want to align the `<div>` element which _contains_ two `<span>` elements and one `<form type="text">` element, vertically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here ya go, http://jsfiddle.net/EWkMA/

CSS:

```
div#middle {
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='middle'>
    <input type='text' value='test'/><br/>
    <span>a</span><br/>
    <span>two</span>
</div>
```